# Error connecting my MYSQL database with Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, database, coldfusion, connection

I'm getting the following error message in CF11 when  trying to access my MYSQL database on a local machine:

Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
The error occurred in D:/inetpub/wwwroot/Applewood Community_03/textareaTest.cfm: line 9
   Called from using password: line -1
  Called from using password: line -1

I created the DB in the admin page. I also verified the DB. I can open the database in the command prompt. The only thing I can't do is connect it in CF11. Everything tells me the DB is connected and working fine, just not when I view the data in the web page. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show your cfquery tag.  The "called from using password" stuff is suspicious.

Comment: <cfquery datasource="customer" username="root" password="mypassword" name="getCategory1" >
     SELECT *
     FROM op_categories WHERE idOpCategories = 1

</cfquery>

Comment: If you already supplied the username/password in the DSN, you do not need to do so in the cfquery tags.  The two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: *username="root"* Side note, for security reasons never use "root". Instead, create another user account and assign the required privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just removed the username and password and now everything works.

Even though it works, I'm curious why it wouldn't want a username or password?

Comment: Didn't you provide the credentials in CFAdmin?

Comment: I just left the Admin at it's basic settings except the error handling. I turned all those on.